# uwsgi native https support?

Tags: https, uwsgi

I want to run my uwsgi server with https. Yes, I know it is a wrong thing to do in production.
The docs clearly say: configure your keys and use `--https` option: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTPS.html

Problem is, no such option exists, apparently:

```
$ uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --https 0.0.0.0:8443,~/my.crt,~/my.key
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--https'
getopt_long() error
$ uwsgi --version
2.0.11
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like the uWSGI dox lied. :/

Comment: What does `uwsgi --help | grep https` reveal? How was it installed?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `uwsgi` on Alpine Linux, no https options at all.

Comment: @xj9 Looks like there's no such option after all.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to rebuild uwsgi with ssl-support:

On a debian server with uwsgi installed by pip this would be (as root):

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
pip install uwsgi -I --no-cache-dir
```

`-I` for reinstall, `--no-cache-dir` for building new from scratch.